# Apache sub-sites

Tags: apache

I want to match  *www.mydomain.org*  to a different DocumentRoot as *www.mydomain.org/private/*

but found no hint in the apache docs.

Can anyboydy help me ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the mod_alias module:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_alias.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html

"The Alias directive allows documents to be stored in the local filesystem other than under the DocumentRoot. URLs with a (%-decoded) path beginning with url-path will be mapped to local files beginning with directory-path. The url-path is case-sensitive, even on case-insenitive file systems."

Example:

```
Alias /private /opt/private
<Directory /opt/private>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```